# Regex for text between double square brackets

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

this is my sample text:

```
text text text
[[{"fid":"3228","view_mode":"full","fields":{"format":"full","field_file_image_alt_text[und][0][value]":"text text text","field_file_image_title_text[und][0][value]":"","field_file_image_gallery_content[und][0][value]":"","field_file_image_gallery_content[und][0][format]":"full_html"},"type":"media","link_text":null,"attributes":{"alt":"text text","height":"647","width":"421","class":"media-element file-full"}}]]
```

I want to extract the text between the double brackets: `[[` and `]]`.

This is my approach:

```
preg_match_all("/\[[^\]]*\]/", $txt, $matches);
```

But it works only for text between singles brackets like `[` and `]`.

How does my regex to have to look like, to extract the text between double brackets?

Comment: Shouldn't the regex be `/\[\[(.*)\]\]/i`?

Answer (score 4):

Try this - first match:

```
if (preg_match('/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/i', $buffer, $regs)) {
    $result = $regs[1];  // Matched text
} else {
    $result = "";
}
```

Or this - iteration over all matches:

```
preg_match_all('/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/i', $buffer, $regs, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($regs[1]); $i++) {
    // Matched text = $regs[1][$i];
}
```

If you have no real argument to process the data like this, follow Borodin's answer and use **json_decode**. This probably would be better.

Comment: This was downvoted.  I had to up vote just to get it to 0. I tested this and it worked without a hitch.  Whomever is down voting like this is not helping anyone and in fact led me away for a minute.  That is very disruptive.  Good job btw man. It was the perfect answer; honestly, wtf?

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to process JSON data using a regular expressions. That's fraught with danger.

Use  [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)